# Use orWhere with 'whereHas' and 'with' in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I am trying to check a search value in a renationalized query to search if it matches with 3 different columns

```
    Table |  Column
-------------------
    Order     code
    Customer  name
    Customer  dni
```

I tried several ways but it just woks with the value name.
This is what I have now:

```
$search = "%{$searchQuery}%";

$constraint = function ($query) use ($search){
    $query->where('name', 'like', $search)
          ->orWhere('dni', 'like', $search);
};
return Order::with(['customer' => $constraint])
                ->whereHas('customer', $constraint)
                ->orWhere('code', 'like', $search)
                ->paginate(15);
```

If I search by name it works, but if I put part of the dni it says

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I am accessing the value in the view like this:

```
{{ $order->customer->dni }}
```

or for example

```
{{ $order->code }}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're messing the `whereHas` subquery by using `orWhere`. It's something like this now: `where fk = pk and name like $search or dni like $search`, while you need to enclose `(name like $search or dni like $search)`:

```php
$constraint = function ($query) use ($search){
  $query->where(function ($wheres) use ($search) {
    $wheres->where('name', 'like', $search)
          ->orWhere('dni', 'like', $search);
  });
};
```

Comment: This should be upvoted a good thousand times. Never saw it before and explains A LOT.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting search data from a input text box named `search`.

Your code in controller should be like this:

```
$search = Input::get('search');

$constraint = function ($query) use ($search){
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
        ->orWhere('dni', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
};
return Order::with(['customer' => $constraint])
    ->whereHas('customer', $constraint)
    ->orWhere('code', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
    ->paginate(15);
```

> This code is not tested.

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you remove the $constraint from the with() statement.

```
$search = "%{$searchQuery}%";

$constraint = function ($query) use ($search){
    $query->where('name', 'like', $search)
          ->orWhere('dni', 'like', $search);
};
return Order::with('customer')
                ->whereHas('customer', $constraint)
                ->orWhere('code', 'like', $search)
                ->paginate(15);
```

I have not tested this solution but everything else in your code samples looks to be correct.

EDIT: If this does not fix the problem, it would be helpful to see what else is going on in your template. You might need dd() your $order and/or $order->customer to see what values are making it into your template.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it like this:

```
public function search($searchQuery)
{
    $search = "%{$searchQuery}%";

    return Order::with('customer')
                    ->orWhereHas('customer', function($query) use ($search){
                        $query->where('dni', 'like', $search);
                    })
                    ->orWhereHas('customer', function($query) use ($search){
                        $query->where(DB::raw('CONCAT_WS(" ", name, lastname)'), 'like', $search);
                    })
                    ->orWhere('code', 'like', $search)
                    ->paginate(15);
}
```

Don't know if it has performance issues...